# Как правильно утилизировать DbContext от Entity Framework в ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

При работе с Entity framework-ом появился такой вопрос. Когда DbContext закрывает соединение с базой? Решил добавить Dispose к нему. При каждом запросе вызывается конструктор DbContext-а, но Dispose не вызывается. В итоге возник следующий вопрос. Как правильно оформлять запросы, нужно ли использовать using, или о правильном очищении ресурсов можно не думать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: соединение с БД берется из пула соединений и туда возвращается, это механизм ADO.NET, поверх которого построен EF. Контекст сам желательно использовать с Using, но это не всегда можно сделать, в зависимости от того, как вы его создаете и какой у него срок жизни.  Dispose по идее должен вызываться через финализатор сборщиком мусора, потому если вы вручную его не вызвали, то он все равно вызовется когда нибудь.

Comment: EF как правило сам умеет управлять своими соединениями достаточно эффективно, ваша задача не мусорить самому и не оставлять повисшие ссылки где-нибудь.

Comment: @tym32167 вот не надо ерунду советовать. Даже когда внешние ресурсы прибирает сборщик мусора - их утечка всё ещё неприятна.

Comment: @AlexKrass нет, не умеет

Comment: @PavelMayorov с каким именно советом из моего коммента не согласны то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285965/9033215 Вообще в большинстве источников упоминается и где-то даже был пост от разработчиков EF (но тут уже могу наврать), что он прекрасно умеет делать все сам без вашей помощи. Если только это не совсем какая-то старая версия EF или вы не хотите в ручном режиме управлять соединениями.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вроде нашел еще одну интересную ссылку, которую читал давно https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/